# My site needs some security patches applied

Tags: security, ee-1.13

I'm having trouble finding the instructions for applying a security patch.  My hosting provider says I need to apply SUPEE-6285. I found a page for that on the Magento site [here](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6285) and the instructions say this:

> Enterprise Edition Merchants: Go to MY ACCOUNT, select the Downloads tab, and then navigate to Magento Enterprise Edition > Support Patches. Look for the folder titled “Security Patches – July 2015.” Merchants can also upgrade to the latest version of the Enterprise Edition and receive the security fixes as part of the core code.

The words "MY ACCOUNT" are a link but when I go there the page is blank.  If I click the My Account link in the upper corner of the site I go to a page but there is no Downloads tab.

Can someone help?

Comment: You need to log in with the account the enterprise edition is registred for. Also this forum is the wrong place to ask questions like this (i think), you might have more luck on the official Magento forum with problems related to magento.com: https://community.magento.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to log in to your Magento Account to download security patches if you are using Magento Enterprise Edition. Magento Community patches are available through the link below and do require you to be logged into your account.

If you are unsure of how to apply your patches, please find someone that can help you. Depending on the patch you may have to revert a previous patch version to apply the new one. Taking a DB backup of the site you are applying to is a must and you should always test on a local/dev environment. Some hosting providers will install the patch if you ask them to.

Magento Community Patch download -> Click Release Archived
https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?_ga=1.4273531.99144044.1487208527

Installing magento patches:
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/installing-magento-patches.html